# get a value through a relationship in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, entity-relationship

I have 2 entities - "Teacher" and "Subjects", and 2 controllers, AddSubject and Subject manager. Entity "subject" has a relationship "teacher". In my AddSubjectController i am adding a subject with choosing a teacher from UIPickerView

```
Subjects *subject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Subjects" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
int selectedRow = [teacherPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];


subject.name = nameOfSubjectTextField.text;
subject.article = notesTextView.text;
subject.teacher = [teacherForSubjectArray objectAtIndex:selectedRow];
```

teacherForSubjectArray is an array with objects from Core Data

```
- (NSArray *)takeTeacherForSubject {

    managedObjectContext = [AppDelegate sharedDelegate].managedObjectContext;

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];

    NSEntityDescription *description = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Teacher" inManagedObjectContext:
                                        managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:description];

    NSError *requestError = nil;

    teacherForSubjectArray = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&requestError] mutableCopy];

    if (requestError) {
        NSLog(@"%@" , [requestError localizedDescription]);
    }
    return teacherForSubjectArray;

}
```

then in my SubjectManager i am trying to show this data in UITable View, taking it from core data before

```
- (NSArray *)takeSubjectFromCoreData {

    managedObjectContext = [AppDelegate sharedDelegate].managedObjectContext;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];

    NSEntityDescription *description = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Subjects" inManagedObjectContext:
                                            managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:description];

    NSError *requestError = nil;
    subjectsResultArray = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&requestError] mutableCopy];

    if (requestError) {
        NSLog(@"%@" , [requestError localizedDescription]);
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", subjectsResultArray);

    return subjectsResultArray;
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    Subjects *objectSubject = [subjectsResultArray objectAtIndex:(long)indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [subjectsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"subjectCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *subjectName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [objectSubject valueForKey:@"name"]];
    NSString *teacherOfSubject = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", objectSubject.teacher];
    cell.textLabel.text = subjectName;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = teacherOfSubject;

    return cell;
}
```

But there is a problem with teacherOfSubject, i get not the current  value, but a path, or NSmanagedObject instead of value that i need, something like

0x7a6806d0 x-coredata://6DB0CDAF-5C8C-4128-BB43-D0EC10EA41D6/Teacher/p2.

i know that answer should be very simple, but i am tired of trying to solve it by myself.

Comment: if my question isn't clear enough, say it, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
NSString *teacherOfSubject = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", objectSubject.teacher];
```

is giving you a string representation of the Teacher relationship of your Subjects - i.e. a reference to the object, not to a particular property. What you presumably want is to reference some property of the Teacher, such as the name.  Assuming you have created subclasses for your two entities, you can use:

```
NSString *teacherOfSubject = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", objectSubject.teacher.name];
```

If not, use:

```
NSManagedObject *teacher = [objectSubject valueForKey:@"teacher"];
NSString *teacherOfSubject = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [teacher valueForKey:@"name"];
```

Obviously amend `name` to match whatever property you wish to use.

Comment: understood. to get name i need do objectSubject.teacher.firstName(thats attribute in a Teacher entity). Thank you.